# Create archive is gone in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, archive, thunar

In Thunar, there was always a command to archive files in the right-click menu. It's gone now. I think it's because the archive manager has been changed in 18.04. file-roller is still installed, though.

```
file-roller 3.28.0, Copyright © 2001-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

(file-roller:7171): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:47:14.428: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3841:23: Junk at end of value for outline-offset
```

Albeit, there is an error.

How do I get that functionality back?

Comment: @Terrance Done that, still not there. If it helps, it's Thunar 1.6.15

Comment: `apt install thunar-archive-plugin`

Comment: @sudo Sorry, just got back to this thread now. Yes, you have; `thunar-archive-plugin` worked. Thank you!

Comment: @DKBose Just did that :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apt install thunar-archive-plugin
```